# Interpretation of a braised lamb dish description from a menu

Tags: lamb, spaghetti, menu-planning

I was tantalized by the description of a braised lamb dish earlier today at an Italian restaurant at the Hyatt I am staying at.

I was expecting a braised cut of lamb covered with sauce on a bed of pasta. I assumed the sauce would have minced meat.
[image]
However what I got served was essentially what looked like spaghetti bolognise ( which wasn't bad at all!) But just not what I had imagined from the menu description. So basically the fish served had no lamb cut. Except the ground beef ( or lamb) that made it into the sauce.
[image]

Just wanted to get some opinions from foodies. Was I wrong to expect what I was expecting? How would you interpret the menu description below? The "&" made me imagine there's two things there but in hindsight maybe I was over expecting things?

Comment: There's a trick I learned many years ago when travelling to places where the menus are multi-lingual. After reading the fourth or fifth item described as something like "meat sauce with paste" I flipped to the Italian page… where everything had a proper, recognisable name. Over-translation is a common issue.

Answer (score 7):

I agree that the "lamb & minced meat" phrasing makes it sound like these will be present as separate components and a different phrasing would have been clearer – but I think the thing to focus on here is the headline 'Meat Sauce', which is what you got.

A dish where a chunk of lamb was the main element wouldn't have that heading, so I think you have focused on the wrong part of the menu and this is behind your disappointment.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't expect anything except that there's some kind of meat involved.  The description is clearly gibberish, either because of poor translation from another language, or being written by AI or by a busy cook on the back of a napkin.

For example, "24 hour braised prime cuts of lamb" makes no sense on its own; nobody would cook a lamb chop for 24 hours, nor would you want to eat it if they did.

In cases like this, you want to ask what you'll actually be getting.  Because if the description is clearly nonsense, then you really have no idea.

Comment: I agree with you entirely. Just wanted a 2nd opinion on whether this is gibberish or I was incapable of correct interpretation.

Comment: Anyways it was a Hyatt restaurant and advertising a house special. So i thought couldn't be too bad a risk.

Comment: I've had terrible dishes in hotel restaurants before.  Just sayin'